# Android TextView Marqee

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to create a magic mirror application that shows the headlines. I successfully grabbed the headlines by RSS and I mashing 3 of the top headlines into on string. When I add the text to the marquee it only shows the last headline.

Headline string sample:

```
US election: Trump 'encourages Russia to hack Clinton emails' | France church attack: Killers 'pledged allegiance to IS' in video | UN condemns 'barbaric' Boko Haram violence in Nigeria
```

Part of the Layout

```
        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/news_headline"
    style="@style/MirrorListText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textSize="@dimen/mirror_cur_event_text_size"
    tools:text=""
        tools:visiblity="visible" />
```

Function that sets the textview 
EDIT added the whole function

```
private NewsModule.NewsListener mNewsListener = new NewsModule.NewsListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNewNews(String headline) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(headline)) {
                mNewsHeadline.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mNewsHeadline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d("NEWSMODULE", headline);
                mNewsHeadline.setText(headline);
                mNewsHeadline.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    };
```

EDIT: Added Class that pulls the RSS

```
public class NewsModule {
    public interface NewsListener {
        void onNewNews(String headline);
    }

    public static void getNewsHeadline(final NewsListener newsListener) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                newsListener.onNewNews(s);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RSSReader rssReader = new RSSReader();
                String url = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml?edition=us";
                try {
                    RSSFeed feed = rssReader.load(url);
                    Log.d("NEWSMODULE", "successful load");

                    String headlines = feed.getItems().get(0).getTitle();// + feed.getItems().get(1).getTitle() + feed.getItems().get(2).getTitle();
                    Log.d("NEWSMODULE",headlines);
                    return headlines;
                } catch (RSSReaderException e) {
                    Log.d("NEWSMODULE", "Error parsing RSS");
                    return null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // not great to catch general exceptions, but this lib is being sketchy
                    Log.d("NEWSMODULE", "Error parsing RSS");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

I know I am successfully passing the full string to the function, but the only headline appears and moves around is

```
"UN condemns 'barbaric' Boko Haram violence in Nigeria"
```

Comment: does your textview shows double quotes at start and end of text??

Comment: Does `Log.d("NEWSMODULE",headline);` print the correct result?

Comment: no quotes at the end.. and Log.d("NEWSMODULE",headline) does print correctly

Comment: after doing some research, the problem is the AsyncTask. It is taking the focus away from the TextView, therefore, only showing part of the text that set. I am not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

The gravity for the TextView was not correct. After I put `android:gravity="left"` 
inside as one of the attributes, the marquee worked like a charm.